# Выборка из таблиц используя связь многие-ко-многим

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть три таблицы autor, book, rubric. И есть еще две связывающие таблицы bookautor и bookrubric.

**Таблица RUBRIC:** `RubricID, RubricName`

**Таблица AUTOR:** `AutorID, FirstName, LastName`

**Таблица BOOK:** `BookID, BookName, book_photo`

**Таблица BOOKAUTOR:** `BookID, AutorID`

**Таблица BOOKRUBRIC:** `BookID, RubricID`

Я хочу написать в одном запросе, запрос который будет возвращать book_name, first_name, last_name и rubric_name.
Я написал два отдельных запроса которые мне выводят результат, вот они:

```
SELECT 
book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName 
FROM bookautor 
JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID 
JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID;
```

и

```
SELECT rubric.RubricName 
FROM bookrubric 
JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID;
```

Но я не могу понять как это можно написать в одном запросе SELECT.
Вот что я пробую:

```
 SELECT 
 book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName, rubric.RubricName 
 FROM bookautor,bookrubric 
 JOIN book ON book.BookID=bookautor.BookID 
 JOIN autor on autor.AutorID=bookautor.AutorID 
 LEFT JOIN rubric ON rubric.RubricID=bookrubric.RubricID;
```

Но такой запрос вызывает ошибку `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'bookautor.BookID' in 'on clause'`
Как это сделать в одном запросе?

Comment: Проверьте верно ли вы указываете поле 'BookID' в таблице 'bookautor'.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вставить одинарные кавычки в название таблиц и полей.
И прими к сведению то, что в именовании mysql не принято использовать буквы в верхнем регистре и кэмэлКейсом. Используй названия типа book_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.BookName,a.FirstName, a.LastName, r.RubricName
FROM BOOK b
INNER JOIN 
BOOKAUTOR ba ON ba.BookID=b.BookID
INNER JOIN
AUTOR a ON a.AutorID=ba.AutorID
INNER JOIN 
BOOKRUBRIC br ON br.BookID=b.BookID
INNER JOIN 
RUBRIC r ON r.RubricID=br.RubricID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT book.BookName, autor.FirstName, autor.LastName, rubric.RubricName
FROM book
LEFT JOIN bookautor ON (bookautor.BookID = book.BookID)
LEFT JOIN autor ON (autor.AutorID = bookautor.AutorID)
LEFT JOIN bookrubric ON (bookrubric.BookID = book.BookID)
LEFT JOIN rubric ON (rubric.RubricID = bookrubric.RubricID)
```